# How to get renamed cocoa bundle name

Tags: swift, cocoa, bundle

By using "kCFBundleNameKey" key we can get bundle name.

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String
```

Now, Consider there is an app called ABC.app, if we duplicate the app then build name becomes "ABC Copy.app". I don't find any related constant in "Bundle.main.infoDictionary" to get duplicated build name.

Thanks

Comment: by duplicating an app you assume duplicating a target?

Comment: No, just like you duplicate a txt file.

Comment: don't understand you :) can you describe your actions?

Comment: I found a way to get bundle/file name with this code. let bundlePath = ((Bundle.main.bundlePath as NSString?)?.lastPathComponent as NSString?)?.deletingPathExtension